# I can't recieve a reply from a socket in Java

Tags: java, sockets

I’ve this problem.
I need to read the weight from a scale connected on local network.
From hyperterminal I connect to a ip with port, open connection,I send the string “XN” , enter, and the scale write a new line in Hyperterminal with weight as string.
I’ve tried to do the same from code using socket but I can get any result in return.
Can you address me to some kind of example to help me ? This is the code I've tried without success.

```
Socket echoSocket = null;
DataOutputStream os = null;
DataInputStream is = null;
try
{
    echoSocket = new Socket(IpBilancia, Porta);
    os = new DataOutputStream(echoSocket.getOutputStream());
    is = new DataInputStream(echoSocket.getInputStream());
}
catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    System.err.println("Don't know about host: " + IpBilancia);
}
catch (IOException e) 
{
    System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to" + IpBilancia);
}
    try
    {
        os.writeBytes("XN");
        os.writeByte('\n');
        os.flush();
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String Peso;
        while ((Peso = input.readLine()) != null) 
        {

            System.out.println("echo: " + is.readLine());
        }
        os.close();
        is.close();
        echoSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("I/O failed on the connection to" + IpBilancia);
    }
```

edit1 :

```
Socket echoSocket = null;
DataOutputStream os = null;
DataInputStream is = null;
try
{
    echoSocket = new Socket(IpBilancia, Porta);
    os = new DataOutputStream(echoSocket.getOutputStream());
    is = new DataInputStream(echoSocket.getInputStream());
}
catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    System.err.println("Don't know about host: " + IpBilancia);
}
catch (IOException e) 
{
    System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to" + IpBilancia);
}
try
{
    os.writeBytes("XN");
    os.writeByte('\n');
    os.flush();
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String Peso;
    while ((Peso = input.readLine()) != null) 
    {

        System.out.println("echo: " + is.readLine());
    }
    os.close();
    is.close();
    echoSocket.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("I/O failed on the connection to" + IpBilancia);
}
```

The debug stay stuck on the while loop. It don't enter in the loop .
It stop here
while ((Peso = input.readLine()) != null)
doing nothing.

Comment: Note that inside the `while` loop you are doing `is.readLine()` so you are reading a line **two times**, but only one line is written to `os`. Did you mean: `System.out.println("echo: " + Peso);` instead?

Comment: Yes. But the problem is that input.readLine() is empty. I don't understand why this. Doing it from hyperterminal give a result. Thank for your help

Comment: You ignored @Jesper comment, so I'll repeat it. You are calling `is.readLine()` twice in the loop, **and throwing away the result of the first is.readLine()**.

Comment: Don't even enter there.
It stop in the
while ((Peso = input.readLine()) != null)
It don't find any line to read and stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works fine with a netcat dummy server (your code with Jesper's note):

```
try
{
    os.writeBytes("XN");
    os.writeByte('\n');
    os.flush();
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String peso;
    while ((peso = input.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println("echo: " + peso);
    }
    os.close();
    is.close();
    echoSocket.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("I/O failed on the connection to" + IpBilancia);
}
```

You use hyperterminal to try your server manually, thus I supose that your are on Windows.

Perhaps the config of your hyperterminal use a CRLF as End Of Line?

In this case, try to use:

```
os.writeBytes("XN");
os.writeByte('\r');
os.writeByte('\n');
```

to have the same EOL with your Java client.